# Property 'getFrameworkComponentInstance' does not exist on type 'ICellRendererComp'

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to get the instance of cell renderer (Angular component) on rowSelected event handler:

```
onRowSelected($event) {
    var selectedRow = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex($event.rowIndex);
    var params = { columns: ['added'], rowNodes: [selectedRow]};
    var instances = this.gridApi.getCellRendererInstances(params);
    if (instances.length > 0) {
        var wrapperInstance = instances[0].getFrameworkComponentInstance();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the error during the compilation of angular application (ts):

> Property 'getFrameworkComponentInstance' does not exist on type 'ICellRendererComp'

The implementation comes from official documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/ (find Accessing Cell Renderer Instances).

[Here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/b10d5b54ef66e0772cd544975a7a6997c6b94d0f/packages/ag-grid-angular/src/angularFrameworkComponentWrapper.ts) is possible factory method which define public `getFrameworkComponentInstance`.

It's unexpected situation because when I debug this method I can get the renderer with method `getFrameworkComponentInstance` on `instances[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

From what I saw in the interfaces of the **ICellRenderer**, the interface **ICellRendererComp** doesn't have the function getFrameworkComponentInstance.

[image: Interfaces of ICellRendererComp]

I've worked a lot with ag-grid-angular and I found out that sometimes, the interfaces are not relevant to what's really in the object (Missing functions/variables).

The problem is mainly because of tslint that doesn't trust the method since it isn't in the interface. To fix that, I created my own custom interface that extends the ICellRendererComp but with the function.

[image]

That way when you try to call your instance you can cast it to your interface. I tried a lot of things and only this worked for me.

[image]

Comment: This workaround works. The problem is not related to tslint but to tsc. Still searching for another solution or waiting for the other answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the reasons in the above answer, however a shorter approach has saved me time.
Instead of creating a custom interface, the following has worked for me -

```
if (instances.length > 0) {
        var cellRenderer: any = instances[0];
        var wrapperInstance = cellRenderer.getFrameworkComponentInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**From v27 of AG Grid**

You no longer need to use the method `getFrameworkComponentInstance()`, as your Angular component will be returned directly from `getCellRendererInstances()`. So you can loop through the components and call their methods directly.

```
const instances = this.gridApi.getCellRendererInstances(params) as MyComponent[];

instances.forEach((instance) => {
  instance.myComponentFunction();
});
```

See updated documentation here: [Component Cell Renderer](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#accessing-cell-renderer-instances)